# How to add specific js and css to a particular page in joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I have added the html code using sp page builder extension also need to add css and js to this particular page in joomla 3. i am using t3 blank template is there any procedure to add this or any shortcut

```
<head>
  <title>Web Interactive</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

  <meta name="generator" content="xxxx 3.8.1">

  <!-- favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="media/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="media/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="media/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="media/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="media/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


  
  <script src="xx.js"></script>
  <script src="xxxx.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Interactive.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support. @NeilRobertson recommends this potential duplicate: [Placing inline javascript into the head tags of one page only](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22010/12352)

Answer (score 2):

Joomla's Documentation about adding CSS or JS to the document head: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$document = Factory::getDocument();

$document->addStyleSheet("...demo.css", array('version'=>'auto'));
$document->addScript("...demo.js", array('conditional'=>'lt IE 9'));
```

That method still works.

You could also use the HTMLHelper to add CSS/JS to the document header

```
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
HTMLHelper::_(
    'stylesheet',
    'com_foo/foo.css', 
    ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]
);

HTMLHelper::_(
'script',
'com_foo/foo.js',
['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]
);
```

To add your CSS/JS to specific pages, you could add it within some check for the page (on option/view/id or the menu item via Itemid)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you should check which page you need via this way:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$app = Factory::getApplication();
$option = $app->input->get('option'); // your component like com_content, com_virtuemart etc.
$view = $app->input->get('view'); // view in your component 
$id = $app->input->get('id'); // id of item of your component: product, article or any you need.
```

And so on, you should find your conditions and then check it in if-else construction.

```
if ($option == 'com_content' && $id == '123456') {    
    HTMLHelper::_(
        'stylesheet',
        'com_foo/foo.css', 
        ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]
    );

    HTMLHelper::_(
        'script',
        'com_foo/foo.js',
        ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true]
    );
}
```

But the true way is to create a system plugin on **onBeforeCompileHead** event and do this job inside the plugin.